# Give IIS privileges to edit scheduled Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

i'm running powershell script within my ASP MVC5 application which is the following

```
schtasks.exe /change /tn TestTask /sd 10/05/2015
```

I need to know how to give my hosted application in SERVER1 privileges through IIS 7.5 to edit this task from web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your website under any user that you wish. Just go to Application Pool
and define the site should be running by which user. For more info you can check this link: [Specify an Identity for an Application Pool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx)

Then you can get enough privileged to that user to run  Powershell shell script

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to schtasks.exe the credentials of a user that has the necessary privileges. See `/u`and `/p` parameters.

This would be, by far, less invasive than changing the application pool identity.